# Create a Dictionary from 2 Lists with Default Keys and the Values from the Lists

Tags: python

So I got 2 lists:

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']    
nums = [1, 2, 3]
```

Desired results:

```
dict = {
'Letter': 'A',
'Number': 1,
'Letter' : 'B',
'Number': 2,
'Letter' : 'C',
'Number': 3,
}
```

I found many solutions for simply combining dicts or creating a dict with dicts but nothing to solve this.

What would be the way to get this result?

Comment: It's not possible to achieve the expected result: dictionaries doesn't allow duplicate keys (in your case, "Letter" and "Number"). Are you looking for a list of dictionaries?

Comment: @j1-lee - It's not the expected result, but valid python.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Oh you are right, it is valid but it is not sensible.

Comment: You would have to do a nested dictionary if you want to use `'Letter'` or `'Number'` each time

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way to do it to get the key the same way as in your example

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']    
nums = [1, 2, 3]

dict = {}
dict['Number'] = {}
dict['Letter'] = {}

for x in range(len(letters)):
    dict['Letter'][letters[x]] = letters[x]
    dict['Number'][nums[x]] = nums[x]

print(dict)
```